# Retrieving geolocation in Java Web Start

Tags: java, geolocation, gps, java-web-start

I'm helping develop a Java Web Start* application and am looking for ways to retrieve the user's location. An ideal solution would be something like [JSR-179](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location_API_for_Java_ME) which uses the best available hardware, but failing that then interfacing more directly with GPS hardware (if available) is one possible option.

**Has anyone out there implemented something like this, and if so what approach did you take?**

Since I haven't been able to find any JSR-179-like APIs out there, I'm investigating a couple of potential solutions, but they both have drawbacks:

1. Read GPS data from a (virtual) serial port.

   - Would only support hardware which interfaced via a serial port.
   - As far as I'm aware we can't automatically detect which port to use, so would have to allow the user to configure this. This would be far from ideal!
2. Make use of HTML 5's [Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html), interfacing with it via the [ScriptEngine API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html).

   - I've never used either of these before, so I've no idea how feasible this is at this point!

**Can anyone suggest other potential approaches, or tell me if either of my ideas are dead-ends?**

*Though we currently use Web Start, and would prefer to continue doing so, we might consider dropping that in favour of something like [getdown](http://code.google.com/p/getdown/) if that would allow us to implement geolocation.

**Edit:**
An additional requirement I didn't originally state is that we need to be able to track the user's *current* location, not just the location they were at when they launched the app.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deploying your application as a Java Web Start application you could deploy it as an applet. In this case it becomes possible to call the browser API through [LiveConnect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html).

Comment: Definitely the best suggestion so far. We have a requirement for an offline mode, but could probably still provide that if we have getdown (or similar) download the web page as well as the applet. I'm going to leave this open for a couple more days, but I suspect the bounty will be yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

The ScriptEngine API will not help you because it's not linked to the browser supporting the Geolocation API. Also, a Java Web Start is completely independent from the browser (you can close the browser and the application will keep working, unlike an applet), so it's not possible to call the Geolocation API.

A solution would be to provide the location parameter to the JWS application via an external mechanism that would use the HTML5 Geolocation API. For example, instead of calling directly the JNLP file for launching the application, you would load a page with a JavaScript snippet that query the Geolocation API and then call the URL of a JSP file:

```
http://www.example.com/myapp/launcher.jsp?latitude=....&longitude=....
```

The `launcher.jsp` page will generate the JNLP file with the appropriate parameters:

```
<resources>
  <property name="jnlp.myapp.latitude"  value="<%= request.getParameter("latitude") %>"/>
  <property name="jnlp.myapp.longitude" value="<%= request.getParameter("longitude") %>"/>
</resources>
```

And you can then retrieve the coordinates in your application as system properties.

This will work if you are only interested in the static location of the user. If the user moves you won't be able to track him.

Comment: Unfortunately we need to track moving users. I'll update the original question to make this clear.

Comment: As I understand it, whether the ScriptEngine API will allow me to use the Geolocation API depends entirely on whether the JavaScript engine (Rhino by default I believe) supports it. Is that correct? I haven't been able to find any info on whether Rhino supports the Geo API, but I haven't looked that hard (yet)...

Comment: The JavaScript engine in Java doesn't support any of the browser JavaScript APIs. You can use it for general scripting, but not for anything web related (no DOM API, no XMLHttpRequest, no webstockets, etc)

Comment: Aha, I was worried that might be the case. :(

Comment: Another point, just for posterity: Your JSP solution would only work if the users always launched the app from the web page; otherwise you'd get a cached JNLP with an old location...

Answer (score 0):

A question and idea more than an answer, but here goes.

What hardware are your users running on? I am guessing a laptop.
Could you insist that the user also has a smartphone and write a small app which would query their GPS position and report it to your main app?
(They may have smartphones already so this may not be an excessive requirement)

This reporting could be done by the phone uploading the position to a central db on the internet, and the app downloading that info, or it could be sent from the phone to the laptop wirelessly somehow.

Comment: ;]. Come outside and join me, the air is wonderful...!  (you may end up out here eventually!)